# Moving data from a Text file to MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have data that looks like this:

> # input 1
>
> 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
>
> # output  1
>
> 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
>
> # input 2
>
> 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
>
> # output 2
>
> 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

The data is in a text file. There are about 130 input and output vectors. I basically need to load the data in MATLAB for training a SVM model.
Does anybody know how I can load the data into MATLAB?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `load` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried [load]. The problem is with lines that read #input/output. I am looking for a way to skip/omit those.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html

Comment: http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html

Comment: The above links myt b helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter way of loading your text file:

```
%// Read lines from text file into cell array
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '', 'CommentStyle', '#');
fclose(fid);

%// Convert contents of each cell into a numerical array
C = cellfun(@str2num, reshape(C{1}, [], 2), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The result is a *N*×2 cell array `C` (where *N* is the number of input-output pairs) containing your data.

For the example in your question, `C{1, 1}` stores an input 1×121 array of 1's and 0's, and `C{1, 2}` contains the corresponding 1×10 output array `[1.00 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`.

Comment: Very nice! +1 for `'CommentStyle'` and `cellfun(@str2num ...`. I assume this is tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

You can import text files into MATLAB both interactively as well as programmatically.

To import data interactively, use the Import Tool. You can generate code to repeat the operation on multiple similar files. The Import Tool supports text files, including those with the extensions .txt, .dat, .csv, .asc, .tab, and .dlm. These text files can be nonrectangular, and can have row and column headers. Data in these files can be a combination of numeric and nonnumeric text, and can be delimited by one or more characters.

To import data from text files programmatically, use an import function. Most of the import functions for text files require that all data fields in your file are numeric, and that each row of data has the same number of column

There are many import tools in MATLAB like 'load','textscan',etc

Comment: I have used 'load', 'textscan', and such. The problem is not with importing un-formatted data. 
Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. Appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the lines you don't want start with `#`, you can use something like `textscan` with a simple option: "stop reading when you reach this character".  In that case, reading one line at a time you would get

```
fid = fopen(myFile);
while(~feof(fid))
    myData = textscan(fid, '%[^#]d');
    if numel(myData) > 1
        thisRow = [myData{:}];
    end
end
```

I don't have access to matlab right now but the above should be very close...

I just realized that if your data is in fact alternating "name of vector" and "data of vector", and the name is always preceded by a "#", you can do better:

```
fid = fopen(myFile);
while(~feof(fid))
    myName = textscan(fid, '# %s %d');
    myData = textscan(fid, '%f', Inf);
    if numel(myData) > 1
        varName = sprintf('%s{%d}', myName{1}, myName{2});
        assignin('base', varName,myData); 
    end
end
```

This *might* just do what you really need... or, again, be somewhat close. Experiment with these commands - treat it "for inspiration only".

Comment: Thanks. This might just help.